# Ошибка в html коде

Tags: html, javascript

[image]

В чем ошибка? Если s='asdfasdf', то вставляет без проблем, а вот так не хочет.
Вот код:

```
function add()
        {   
            n_i--;
            i2=n_i+1;
            id_='stroka_'+n_i;
            alert(id_);
            var s ='<tr id="stroka_'+i2+'"> 
                <td style="border-bottom:inherit"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox"  /></td>
                <td align="center" id="family'+id+'" onclick="redact(\'family'+id+'\',\''+id+'\')">'+family_y+'</td>
                <td align="center" id="name'+id+'" onclick="redact(\'name'+id+'\','+id+')">'+name_y+'</td>
                <td align="center" id="otchestvo'+id+'" onclick="redact(\'otchestvo'+id+'\','+id+')">'+otchestvo+'</td>
                <td align="center" id="family_y'+id+'" onclick="redact(\'family_y'+id+'\','+id+')"></td>
                <td align="center" id="name_y'+id+'" onclick="redact(\'name_y'+id+'\','+id+')"></td>
                <td align="center" id="opisanie'+id+'" onclick="redact(\'opisanie'+id+'\','+id+',0,true)"></td>
                <td align="center" id="god'+id+'" onclick="redact(\'god'+id+'\','+id+')"></td>
                <td align="center" id="mesto'+id+'" onclick="redact(\'mesto'+id+'\','+id+')"></td>
                <td id="delete_"'+id+' class="delete" onclick="delete_('+id+',this);" onmouseover="this+style+cursor=\'pointer\'"><hr width="20px"></td>    
            </tr>';
            $('#'+id_).before(s);
            n_i=n_i+2;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript - это не php, в нем такие переносы строк не работают. Пишите все в одну строку или через `s += '...';`

Comment: да так и сделал =) все заработало

Answer (score 2):

В ES-2015 можно делать такие переносы, все что вам для этого нужно, это добавить в начало кода `'use strict';` и заменить "" на ``

```
Var s = `<h1>
    Теперь ошибки не будет
    </h1>`
```

И вместо

```
Var s = "<tr id='stroka_"+i2+"'>";
```

Можно сделать

```
Var s = `<tr id='stroka_${i2}'>`;
```

Answer (score 0):

А если попробовать так:

```
var s="<tr id='stroka_"+i2+"'>";
```

Двойные ковычки внешние, а одинарные внутренние для значений тегов.

Да и еще:

Чтобы многострочные операторы работали как надо - перенос строки можно указывать обратным слешем `"\"`

[Структура javascript](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/foundation/structure)

Comment: не , с должно быть равно всему тексту который сверху!

Comment: Я понял, прост не стал исправлять всё)

Comment: как удалить вопрос?

Comment: Его можно закрыть, или принять ответ)